# Finding the missing sequence number in a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, find, sequence

Hi I have to find a missing number in an xml file. but I feel difficulty to find. Pls suggest some ideas.

### Example

A file contains an `<a>` tag which include id i.e page-1,2... I need to find the missing numbers using jquery.

a.xml

---

```
<p>have a great <a id="page-1"/>day. How are you.</p>
<p><a id="page-2"/>Have a nice day.</p>
<p>How <a id="page-5"/>are you</p>
<p>Life is so exciting<a id="page-6"/></p>
```

My code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {      
        $("#find").click(function(){
            Fname = $("#myFile").val();
            lpage = $("#lpage").val();

            $.get(Fname, function(data){
                var lines = data.split("\n");
                if (lines.match(id="page-)) { //how to use regular exoreessi0n
                    alert("hi");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions with a specific worded problem should show effort and the current code that you have. You are unlikely to get a good response by dumping your question verbatim; explain what you're struggling with and provide clear debugging information.

Comment: You html result isn't valid. `a` isn't self-closing tag. You should close it by `</a>`.

Comment: i am new to this field and now i a blank about this concept. can u suggest some ideas how to search the content id="page- and get the number to check for it sequence

Comment: @Danh No, Check https://jsfiddle.net/kv2oo0p0/ . Browser can't recognize correct count of `a` and return 11 but is 4.

Comment: @Danh I think it is misunderstood of broswer. Because it generate multiple additional `a` tag. https://jsfiddle.net/kv2oo0p0/1/

Comment: @Mohammad I asked a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40059580/how-do-javascript-engine-count-number-of-tag-of-the-html-document-is-ill-formed)

Comment: @Ancy Is index of ids respectively? That means has last `a` largest index?

Answer (score 0):

I'll take some assumptions regarding your input. Please add validations as necessary:

```
var lines = ['<p>have a great <a id="page-1"/>day. How are you.</p>',
    '<p><a id="page-2"/>Have a nice day.</p>',
    '<p>How <a id="page-5"/>are you</p>',
    '<p>Life is so exciting<a id="page-6"/></p>'];

    var sequences = [];
    lines.forEach(function(line) {

        // Not efficient but simple
        // Let jQuery parse this string to object, so we won't need regexp
        var obj = $(line);

        // Assuming there's always A and ID attribute
        var id = obj.find("a").attr("id").split("-");

        // Assuming sequence is always last
        sequences.push(parseInt(id[id.length - 1]));
    });

    sequences.sort();

    // Again, inefficient, but will do the job
    var last = sequences[sequences.length - 1];

    for (var i = last; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (sequences.indexOf(i) < 0) {
            console.log(i + " is missing");
        }
    }
```