# How do javascript engine count number of tag of the HTML document is ill-formed?

Tags: javascript, html

From this question: [Finding the missing sequence number in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40057381/finding-the-missing-sequence-number-in-a-file)

The author gave this example:

```
<p>have a great <a id="page-1"/>day. How are you.</p>
<p><a id="page-2"/>Have a nice day.</p>
<p>How <a id="page-5"/>are you</p>
<p>Life is so exciting<a id="page-6"/></p>
<p id="tag_count"></p>
```

[Mohammad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5104748/mohammad) had convinced me that the given html document is ill-formed by running:

```
document.getElementById('tag_count').innerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName("a").length;
```

And the tag with id `tag_count` is changed to 11.

My question is how do javascript engine make that? It's consistent with both Firefox and Chrome. Is it consistent with other browser or it's some kind of "undefined behavior"?

Comment: It ***is*** "ill-formed", the anchors aren't closed. The browser does however try to fix your mistakes, and how it does that is anyones guess, and not defined by any specific standard.

Comment: @adeneo I know it's ill-formed, I want to ask about the browser behavior

Comment: It's not the JavaScript "engine" that does it, it's the browser's HTML parser and DOM-building code. The JavaScript DOM APIs just look at the DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is how do javascript engine make that?

It doesn't. By the time you're using JavaScript to access the resulting DOM document, the structural problems like unclosed tags have *already* been resolved by the browser's HTML parser. All that's happening in the line of code that you've shown is that the JavaScript engine is asking the DOM how many `a` elements ended up being in the document **after** the HTML, with all its issues, had been parsed.

The [HTML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) has a lot to say about recovering from invalid markup, information and techniques that were determined over a period of 20 years by various browser implementations and eventually agreed to by the members of the [WHAT-WG](https://whatwg.org/) as a common set of error-correction approaches.

Comment: [Section 8.2.8 of the HTML5 document in particular](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#an-introduction-to-error-handling-and-strange-cases-in-the-parser), but it's a vast topic.

Comment: So it will be difference from browser to browser?

Comment: @Danh: It certainly *can* be, depending on the way in which the HTML is invalid, whether that's covered by anything in the spec, and if so whether the browser you're using uses the error recovery for it defined by the spec. Invalid is invalid, you can't expect it to be consistently handled, even if in some cases it will be.